Getting words from a text in PHP codeignter 3
I have this code to check AI content in a text using copyleaks AI API. This is the documentation https://docs.copyleaks.com/docs/copyleaks-documentation/potbjbwncweum-submit-natural-language
public function save_article(){
    $articleText = $this->input->post('articletxt');
    $id = $this->input->post('order'); 
    $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken();
    $copyleaksEndpoint = "https://api.copyleaks.com/v2/writer-detector/$id/check";
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken
    );
    $data = array(
        'text' => $articleText
    );
    $ch = curl_init($copyleaksEndpoint);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($response === false) {
        $error = curl_error($ch);
        echo "cURL Error: " . $error;
    } else {
    $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
    $matches = $responseData['results'];
    $matchedTexts = array();
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $textStart = $match['matches'][0]['text']['chars']['starts'][0];
        $textLength = $match['matches'][0]['text']['chars']['lengths'][0];
        $matchedTexts[] = substr($articleText, $textStart, $textLength);
    }
    $matchedText = implode(" ", $matchedTexts);
    echo $matchedText;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

When echo $matchedText I am getting the entire articleText instead of the AI content
This is my response from the API
{
  "modelVersion": "v5",
  "results": [
    {
      "classification": 1,
      "probability": 0.45004112,
      "matches": [
        {
          "text": {
            "chars": {
              "starts": [
                0
              ],
              "lengths": [
                1586
              ]
            },
            "words": {
              "starts": [
                0
              ],
              "lengths": [
                227
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "classification": 2,
      "probability": 0.8968757,
      "matches": [
        {
          "text": {
            "chars": {
              "starts": [
                1586
              ],
              "lengths": [
                3668
              ]
            },
            "words": {
              "starts": [
                227
              ],
              "lengths": [
                534
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "classification": 1,
      "probability": 0.3241927,
      "matches": [
        {
          "text": {
            "chars": {
              "starts": [
                5254
              ],
              "lengths": [
                3274
              ]
            },
            "words": {
              "starts": [
                761
              ],
              "lengths": [
                470
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "summary": {
    "human": 0.56620634,
    "ai": 0.43379366
  },
  "scannedDocument": {
    "scanId": "5284",
    "totalWords": 1231,
    "totalExcluded": 0,
    "actualCredits": 5,
    "expectedCredits": 5,
    "creationTime": "2024-05-03T12:21:17.4673227Z"
  }
}

Can someone assist in getting the AI content?
